# symfony remove entity mapping doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, entity

When I used "**php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql**"; I have error:

> *->[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
>
>     The table with name 'bissap_forum.category' already exists.*

When I used "php app/console doctrine:mapping:info"; i have :

```
Found 7 mapped entities:

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Category

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Skill

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Image

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\Application

[OK]   BISSAP\PlatformBundle\Entity\AdvertSkill

[OK]   BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity\Category
```

So I have 2 entities with same Name (**Category**), maybe this is why, i have a error, when i use "**php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql**"?!

How can i purged my entities mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a different table name to one of your *Category* entities ?

```
/**
 * My\Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_category_table")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
   ...
}
```

This way, you won't have any conflict anymore.

Comment: It's ok...when I set a different table name; But  **php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql** create all tables. I want generate table only  for : **BISSAP\BodyConceptBundle\Entity** . And i don't know how purged the Doctrine mapping...thank U.

Comment: I resolved my problem! I configured **config.yml** with 2 connections and 2 entityManager. Thank U

Comment: Nice to hear that ! Good job  :)